# CSS background-image URL to Image folder of Sitefinity folder structure

Tags: asp.net, url, content-management-system, sitefinity

I have a Folder Structure as it folows:
`App_Data\Sitefinity\WebsiteTemplates\MySite\App_Themes\Mytheme\Images`
I have images in the Images folder.
What should be the url in main main css file which is used as a theme for most of the pages.
I have tried different variants but unsuccessful.
The css file is located in:
`App_Data\Sitefinity\WebsiteTemplates\MySite\App_Themes\Mytheme\Global`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsure what you mean, but if you are trying to reference a url in a different directory use the following:

```
div { background-image: url('../Images/example.jpg');
```

...instead of:

```
div { background-image: url('/Images/example.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the Images folder under the \Global folder and then in the main css just reference the images by url(images/sprite.png) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

To add images in Sitefinity, you go to Content | Images menu. Then you click on Upload Images button to select an image from your local drive.

To create a folder so you can put your images in, you select Create a Library button. Then you upload your images to it.

To reference the image, just click on it, and select View in Original Size.

That will give you the URL to the image.

```
Example:

http://example.com/images/default-source/MyImages/img.jpg
```

Then you can use that URL to reference your image  in your html style:

```
body {
        background: url('http://example.com/images/default-source/MyImages/img.jpg') no-repeat;
    }
```